# How to send Spring Boot admin client meta data to admin server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have a spring boot application (Spring Boot Admin Client Application) and an Spring Boot Admin server. The client application has actuator module and uses database for its user authentication . The problem is I need to register the same client application to admin server. I cannot write the username and password in plain text in properties file of client application. The server is not able to get the health data for the client . I need some way so that I can register my client application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Make the actuator health endpoint open so that it can be accessed without passing authentication credentials.

   or
2. Publish the username/password as metadata when registering the client application.

Please refer to https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.1.6/#_securing_client_actuator_endpoints:

> When the actuator endpoints are secured using HTTP Basic authentication the SBA Server needs credentials to access them. You can submit the credentials in the metadata when registering the application. The BasicAuthHttpHeaderProvider then uses this metadata to add the Authorization header to access your application’s actuator endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think that option 1 is possible. I need to go with option 2. Can you pls tell me what will be the variable name

Comment: Also, don't forget to add the username/password to your client authentication database.